# Window "frame" rotates even though app is portrait only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on portrait-only app for iOS that even though the interface does not rotate, I'm getting the "frame" rotation animation of the window when rotating the device.

Adding more detail:

- The app is a single window application
- Its native objc, no web view or react native or weird frameworks
- The rectangle in the lower left is added by iOS 11 when you took a screenshot.
- Happens in the device with iOS 11 only, not happening on the simulators.

Graphic reference:
[image]

Comment: There probably is not enough information here to help. Are you working with any non-standard UI frameworks? Have you added any non-standard UIWindows? What is the little rectangle at the lower left? Does this happen on simulator or device or both? Does the view-debugger show extra windows on top of everything else? (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) As given, this likely too vague to troubleshoot unless someone has had this precise issue.

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier, I added some context answering your questions. There is no other window/view on top when debugging view hierarchy